# Cannot prevent Activity restart

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I want to prevent system from restarting my Activity when device `orientation` changed. The `minSdkVersion` has to be 10, the `targetSdkVersion` has to be 15 at least. I'm not able to use `configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` because min SDK version is 10 and "screenSize" value of this attribute only appeared since SDK version 13.

Any suggestions please?

I know there were similar questions answered but still the problem is not solved for me. Please do not suggest to set min SDK version higher than 10 because this cuts off devices running 2.3.x which is 43% of the market. And the target SDK has to be 15 at least.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: set your activity to run in either potrait or landscape mode in manifest file. when screen orientation changes activitiy is recreated. thats how it works

Comment: @Raghunandan Um, no. There are ways to disable the recreation of the activity. That is what OP is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `targetSdkVersion` is 15 or greater, then you need to specify

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

This works on all devices.

Comment: This doesn't work because my min SDK level is 10 and "screenSize" is just undefined for it.

Comment: No, that's not true. It has nothing to do with your minSDK level. It has to do with the SDK you are using to compile and build your APK. If your targetSDK is 15, then you need to build your APK with at least AndroidSDK 15. Just get a later version of the SDK for compiling.

Comment: hmm.. All the time I thought that minSDK level is the SDK level you have to compile with to guarantee that your package can be installed on minSDK level systems. In other words, I can build my package with API 17 and just specifying minSDK 4 in manifest guarantees that package can be installed on 1.6 systems? If you are right then the problem is solved.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the situation. Just compile with most recent SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. ( I've updated my Android SDK, now it contains 10, 16 and 17 APIs. I built my package with level 17 and specified minSdkVersion="10" targetSdkVersion="17", and now this package refuses to install on all my devices (I have bunch of them: one 2.3.3 and several 4.0.x).. So now I will ask you: are you absolutely sure that you can install package built with higher API version to the system with lower API version just by specifying minSdkVersion to correspond the lower one?

Comment: Yes, that should work. We do this all the time. Can you look in the logcat to see why it refuses to install?

Comment: It is possible that you have used parts of a later API that will cause your app to crash or behave strangely on a device with an older API. However, this shouldn't have any impact on whether or not you can install the APK.

Comment: Hmm.. strange.. from Eclipse it works. Eclipse uploads, installs and runs the package on my Galaxy Note wich is 4.0.4. But the same package built with ant from command line refuses to be installed. adb says Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK], and if I manually trying to install package from the file manager the system says about parsing error. (

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, there was a bug in building script on build machine, I'm stupid idiot )) Everything is working just fine, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

As it is descibed on the android developers site

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange

you have to specify

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

if you target API level 12 or below.

Comment: OP says he is targeting API level 15, so this won't help.

Comment: My target API level is 15 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Add this code in your `mainfest.xml` each activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: OP says he is targeting API level 15, so this won't help

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks for you valuable feedback

Comment: This doesn't help as well. Because my target API is 15 the system re-starts my Activity on device rotation because system doesn't see "screenSize" in my configChanges attrib.

Answer (score 0):

if you must not needs specifically configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
You can try this  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden".

By default, when certain key configuration changes happen on Android (a common example is an orientation change), Android fully restarts the running Activity to help it adjust to such changes.

When you define android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" in your AndroidManifest, you are telling Android: "Please don't do the default reset when the keyboard is pulled out, or the phone is rotated; I want to handle this myself. Yes, I know what I'm doing"

Comment: Please read my first post carefully. I know how configChanges works. I just can't put "screenSize" there because my min SDK level is too low for that. But w/o this "screenSize" the system resets my activity on device rotation because the target API is higher than 12.